# Incorrect syntax error message

Tags: petapoco

I have a class User withthe definitions: ID, Name,  CustomerID
and a class Customer with the definitions: ID, Name, Address

I am trying the following query but I`m having the error message, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

What is wrong with the sql?

I am trying to write the sql

```
"select user.ID, user.Name, Customer.Name from User LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER on User.CustomerID = Customer.ID" using relationsExtension  as
```

---

```
return Connection.db.FetchOneToMany<User, Customer>(user =>user.CustomerID,
                "select * from user left join customer on customer.ID= user.CustomerID order by user.name asc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lowercase user is a SQL keyword.  Try like this instead:

select **[User]**.ID, **[User]**.Name, Customer.Name from User ...

Comment: I ran the query I was having trouble with in SQL Management Studio and discovered a similar mistake..